# showing a collection is a basis for the discrete topology on a set $X$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be any set and let

$$ \mathcal{X} := \{ \{ x \} : x \in X \} $$

To prove: $\mathcal{X}$ is a basis for the discrete topology on$X$.

### Try:

First let $x \in X$ be arbitrary, then trivially, we know $x \in \{x \} $. so first condition for a basis is satisfied.

Next, consider two basis elements $\{ x_1 \}$ and $\{ x_2 \}$. IF $x_1 = x_2 $, then $\{x _1 \} \cap \{ x_2 \} = \{ x_1 \} $ and so
$$ x_1 \in \{ x_ 1 \} \subset \{ x_1 \} \cap \{ x_2 \} $$

If $x_1 \neq x_2$, then $\{ x_1 \} \cap \{ x_2 \} = \varnothing$, so the second condition of a basis is trivially satisfied

IS this a correct solution?

Comment: Good job: up to now you checked that it is a basis. Now you have to check that it generates the discrete topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows that your set is a basis for *some* topology, not that it generates the discrete topology. However, any subset $A \subseteq X$ may be written as $A = \bigcup_{a \in A} \{ a \}$, which shows that $A$ is open in that topology.

---

Alternatively, you could have simply used Lemma 13.2 in Munkres, which states:

*Let $X$ be a topological space. Suppose $\mathcal{X}$ is a collection of open sets of $X$ such that for each open set $A$ of $X$ and each $x$ in $A$, there is an element $C$ of $\mathcal{X}$ such that $x \in C \subseteq A$. Then $\mathcal{X}$ is a basis for the topology of $X$.*

Here, of course, each element of $\mathcal{X}$ is open, and any (automatically open) subset $A \subseteq X$, and element $x \in A$, satisfy $x \in \{x\} \subseteq A$.